Python Executable fails to execute powershell script as when ran through python in command prompt
When I run the following Python
subprocess.run(coreCommand, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)

program from the Windows Command Prompt, it executes my Powershell script regularly.
However, when I create a Python executable with the powershell script
.\PythonEnvironment\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --paths .\PythonEnvironment\Lib\site-packages .\src\Update.py --distpath=bin


, it opens the desired program, but only executes it up to the 2nd line before it stops.
Does anyone know a more correct way to emulate Powershell script via the Python executable?
I am trying to run a Powershell script via a Python executable and it does not behave as expected, although it worked both with “Run with Powershell” on the desktop and in the test of the python function in the command prompt
Run via powershell:
Run via powershell
Python is executing the powershell script correctly via command prompt:
Python is executing the powershell script correctly via command prompt:
Python is executing the powershell script correctly via command prompt, so the functions are correct.
Run via python executable:
Run via python executable. After the 2 lines the shell closes
Run via python executable. After the 2 lines the shell closes and does not behave correctly.
We have recently updated to Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redis.
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022

"it opens the desired program, but only executes it up to the 2nd line" - there's only two separate single-line snippets of code in your question, "the 2nd line" doesn't mean anything. Please keep in mind no one can see your screen. Where is the PowerShell script stored? in the bin folder?

@MathiasR.Jessen No, the Powershell script is stored in a folder on the respective PC ./Backend/x.ps1.
When I say it executes up to line 2, I mean the Powershell script launches the desired executable on the respective PC, but it crashes after displaying the 2nd line in the console (i.e. Line 1: "Starting application", Line 2: Application Started, 3. Crash).
In another test it showed me that the desired executable exited with return code 32212254477 (0xC0000005), but this only occurs when I start it through the packaged python executable.
